# Sort List<NumberDetails> lstNumberDetails according to string[] searches

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am searching for data in the database using the number like

```
7892811111 8049311111 725931111
```

but when I am getting result on screen it is in a random order shown in below image in the number column it will display the result in random order

[image]

But I want to  display the result on the screen on the order in which number searches like if I search below number

```
7892811111 8049311111 725931111
```

then when I get a result in the number column first record must be 7892811111 then 8049311111 and the last must be 725931111.

When I am searching for a number it will be stored in an array 
[image]

And when I get the result I am adding the records in a list

```
List<NumberDetails> lstNumberDetails = new List<NumberDetails>();
NumberDetails numDetails = new NumberDetails();
numDetails.Full_Name = dr["Full_Name"].ToString();
numDetails.Number = Convert.ToInt64(dr["Number"].ToString());
numDetails.Address = dr["Address"].ToString();
numDetails.Date = DateofRun.ToString();
numDetails.Circle = dr["Circle"].ToString();
numDetails.Operator = dr["Operator"].ToString();
lstNumberDetails.Add(numDetails);
```

Aan I assign `lstNumberDetails` as an `ItemSorce` of `DataGrid`.
So is it possible to compare Number in `lstNumberDetails` with array beacuse array contains the order in which number searched.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: will `searches` variable contains only three records or `n` records

Comment: n records like how many numbers I searched it contains that much records

Comment: Why don't you search for each number separately and fill the grid correspondingly. Or if you search for all at once what is the problem of reordering data after search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation so posting in the answer.

You can iterate through search array and use **LINQ** **FirstOrDefault()** to find the matching model and add that to you grid datasource.

You could do something like this

```
    public void Search(string[] searches)
    {
        List<NumberDetails> lstNumberDetails = new List<NumberDetails>();
        lstNumberDetails = GetNumbersFromDatabase();

        List<NumberDetails> gridItemSource = new List<NumberDetails>();

        foreach (var item in searches)
        {
            var modelLst = lstNumberDetails.Where(x => x.Number == item);
            if (modelLst.Any())
                gridItemSource.AddRange(modelLst);
        }

        gridName.ItemSource = gridItemSource;
    }
```

Comment: Is there any code tobe written before `foreach` loop?

Comment: It works but if suppose I have two records of the same number then it only takes one record I think because of  FirstOrDefault but I want all values then what I used instead of that  FirstOrDefault

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, Yes i have edited the code. Please check

Comment: @user10753256 I have edited the code based on your requirements

Answer (score 1):

If you can, change your `string[]` to `List<string>`, so you can use `IndexOf` method.

Then you can sort other list accrdingly to it:

```
lstNumberDetails = lstNumberDetails.OrderBy(i => searches.IndexOf(i.Number)).ToList();
```

Comment: Or using the `searches` array as is: `OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(searches, i.Number))`

Comment: And the complexity would be `N*N*log(N)` where `N` is length of `searches`!

Comment: @Theodor it not sort and return output as it is